# EditText in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have EditText in XML looks like

The EditText gets number input. for example 5 as annual rate, I want is also display as 5.00%.

In my Java code I use

```
rateAnnual = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
rateAnnual.setText(String.format("%,.2f",initialMortgage.getRate())+"%");
```

It can display rateAnnual EditText as 5.00%;
The question is when I click the rateAnnual EditText, how it could be only show the real number 5.00 and  remove the % sign for me to update the value?

Comment: Why don't you just create a label right next to the edit field that contains "%"?  That way, you won't need to display it as part of the edit field.

Answer (score 0):

You can either leave the "%" and just select the numbers alone, with this:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setSelection(0, editText.getText().length() - 2);
    }
}
```

OR, get the text and set the text to be everything but the "%" when it is clicked (what you ask for in your question):

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        editText.setSelection(0, editText.getText().length() - 2);
        String currentText = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
        editText.setText(currentText.substring(0,currentText.length() - 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my application...

```
edittext1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            String previousText = null;

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    previousText = edittext1.getText().toString();
                    edittext1.setText("");
                } else {
                    if (edittext1.getText().toString().equals(""))
                        edittext1.setText(previousText);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here I use a focus listener and a string variable named previousText

When the edittext hasFocus I set the previousText variable to the current text and then clear the string in the EditText. This could be easily modified get the "previousText" of

```
 previousText = edittext1.getText().toString().substring(0, 4);
```

You'll also notice what when we lose focus I set the text back to what it was before (if the EditText is left empty) using that same previousText variable you could apply it instead with:

```
 rateAnnual.setText(String.format("%,.2f",initialMortgage.getRate())+"%");
```

This method doesn't exactly replicate what you are asking for but I think the auto-clear feature this provides is quite nice for user experience.